# Is it possible to run Eclipse application and Junit plug-in test simultaneously?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, automation

I have an eclipse application, where in i can create projects and perform some operations. I have written a test cases using Junit for some functions. To run these test functions, i am doing Right click on test class and Run as Junit Plug-in test and it is working properly. I am unable to do both the things at the same time. What i need is to run my eclipse application and Junit plug-in test simultaneously without human intervention. Junit plug-in test has to be done at run time. If there is a way to do that, then please suggest me the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by without human intervention? You can start your application and then you can run your unit test both should work.

Comment: I mean in one click both has to run. If i start my Eclipse application then i am unable to run Junit plug-in test. Giving error ( Couldnot launch the application because the associated workspace is currently in use by anothe eclipse application C:\Workspace\ws1)

Comment: You can use different workspace for two instances.

Comment: Yes it works for different workspace, but i need to use the same workspace for some functions. Is it possible to use the same workspace?

Answer (score 0):

When you run it as Junit plugin test, then it already launches your eclipse plugins (and application), so there is absolutely no need to try to launch *an additional* application.

What probably confuses you, is that the test run and the "normal" manual run use two different workspaces. So if you try to access some files in your test which you created during normal operation, they will not exist. But you should never rely on such things, instead you have to create the necessary artifacts in the test setup method.